# Maintain an updated_by field by using through model Laravel

Tags: laravel, model, eloquent

I can't figure out whats wrong with this model seems im using same method to update 'updated_by' field by using same method . Here Is My Code For Model Address .

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Auth;


class Address extends Model
{
    //declare table since we not generate it using migrate laravel 
    protected $table = 'ADDRESS';

    //assign all field as fillable
    protected $guarded = [];

    // Update field update_by for Address .
    public static function boot()
    {

    //this function not work when updating
    static::updating(function ($Address) {
        $Address->created_by = Auth::user()->id;
    });

    //this function work perfectly 
    static::creating(function ($Address) {
        $Address->updated_by = Auth::user()->id;
        $Address->created_by = Auth::user()->id;
    });

}


function getMember()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Mbrdata','mbr_id');
}
}
```

This code work perfectly on other model , somehow for this model it dont do anything . Ill try to trace an error , somehow I dont know how to debug the error because I dont see any error /exception message . Any suggestion how to debug this type of problem ? since I check my log , also dont log any error .

Correction :-

```php
    public static function boot()
{

    //this function not work when updating
    static::updating(function ($Address) {
        $Address->updated_by = Auth::user()->id;
    });

    //this function work perfectly 
    static::creating(function ($Address) {
        $Address->updated_by = Auth::user()->id;
        $Address->created_by = Auth::user()->id;
    });

}
```

However after the correction still same , the field still not updated with current user .

Comment: When issuing a mass update via Eloquent, the saved and updated model events will not be fired for the updated models. This is because the models are never actually retrieved when issuing a mass update. check documentation

Comment: How about using mutator? https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator

Comment: This may just be a typo in your question, but your `updating()` event method is updating the `created_by` field, not the `updated_by` field.

Comment: Sorry for my typo , actually already done another and its okay , just this one I can't figure where is the root of cause .

Comment: How are you updating the model? BTW: `boot()` should always begin with `parent::boot();`.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `created_by` field in updating method there should be `updated_by`.

You can try this, might be this will help you

```
public static function boot()
{

    //this function not work when updating
    static::updated(function ($Address) {
        $Address->updated_by = Auth::user()->id;
    });

    //this function work perfectly 
    static::creating(function ($Address) {
        $Address->updated_by = Auth::user()->id;
        $Address->created_by = Auth::user()->id;
    });

}
```

Try then above and let me know if that is helpful.